# Thunderbird: how do I stop the main client from minimizing when I open a new window to compose an email?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I can't seem to find any answers for this online.

Every time I double click an email to reply, it opens a new window for me to see the specific email and to type my reply. I'm fine with this behaviour, however in doing this the main client minimises to tray and I have to go into tray to display the main client again. Is there any way to make the main client stay when a pop-out window is created?

Many thanks

Comment: That is **not** the current behavior of Thunderbird: double-clicking simply opens the full email in a new tab, and hitting the **Reply** button opens the composition window but does **not** minimize the parent window. What version of T'bird, on what operating system?